# How to update shopping cart after addtocart button click in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shopping-cart, magento-2.0.7

**My layout file code is**

> cms_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="2columns-left"> 

<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block   class="Vendor\Modulename\Block\ProductTab" name="producttab" template="producttab.phtml" ifconfig="form_section/form_group_general/status">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

**Template file**

```
<?php 

$collection = $block->getProductCollection(); 


?>
<div class="tabContent" id="best_seller">
<div id="best_header"><h1><strong><center></center></strong></h1></div>

<div id="owl-demo-1" class="owl-demo owl-carousel owl-theme">

<?php 

  foreach ($collection as $_productLoad){

      $_items = $_productLoad->getAllItems();
      foreach ($_items as $item) {



        $_product = $this->getLoadProduct($item->getProductId());

    $addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($_product); ?>


<div id="item">


<?php


    $imageUrl = $this->getImageConfig($_product);

?>
    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl();?>"><img src="<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>" ></a>
    <div class="primary header">

    <!-- <a class="product-name"> -->
      <?php

       echo $_product->getName().'<br>';
       ?> 

       <!-- </a> -->

       <div class="price slide"> 
           <?php 
           echo '<strong>'.$specialPrice = $priceHelper->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(), true, false).'</strong>';

            ?>

       </div>
       <div class="secondary header">
           <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $addToCartUrl; ?>" method="post"> 

        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
        <div class="addtocart slide">
         <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary">

           <!-- <span>Add to Cart</span> -->
           <span>
           <img src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Modulename::images/m1.jpg'); ?>" alt="<?php echo __('Add to Cart'); ?>" title="<?php echo __('Add to Cart'); ?>" width="35" height="35" />Add to cart
           </span>
         </button>
         </div>
         <div class="addto_wish_compare slide">
          <a href="#" data-post='<?php  echo $this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->getAddParams($_product) ?>' class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span>
    Add to Wish List</span></a>

          <a href="#" data-post='<?php  echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare')->getPostDataParams($_product);?>'
                data-role="add-to-links"
                class="action tocompare">

        <span><?php  echo __('Compare') ?></span>
          </a>
          </div>
          </form>
          </div>
        </div>
          </div>
      <?php

 }
}

?>
</div>

</div>
```

**My block file**

```
    <?php
    namespace Vendor\Modulename\Block;
    class ProductTab extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {



      protected $_productloader;  

      protected $_productCollectionFactory;
      protected $_productVisibility;
      protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
      protected $orders;
      protected $_scopeConfig;

      public $_listBlock;
      public $_priceHelper;
      public $_imageUrl;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,

       \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,

         \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,

    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,


    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,

    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,

    //These variables Used in phtml file
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $listBlock,

   \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $priceHelper,

   \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageUrl,


    array $data = []
)
{


    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;

    $this->_productloader = $_productloader;

     $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;

    $this->_productVisibility = $productVisibility;

    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;

    $this->_listBlock = $listBlock;
    $this->_priceHelper = $priceHelper;
    $this->_imageUrl = $imageUrl;


    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}



    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }


public function getProductCollection()
{

    if (!$this->orders) {
        $this->orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect('*');

    }
    return $this->orders;
}

 public function getLoadProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
    }


}
```

**Getting Output after clicking of addtocart button**

[image]

Actually, when I checked at checkout page, the product had added successfully

[image]

My problem has why the product has not appeared in the shopping cart after clicking of addtocart button.

Answer (score 1):

add `section.xml` to `etc/frontend` in your custom module and copy paste below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="[frontName]/[ActionPath]/[ActionName]">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

after adding above file run the below commands.

`php bin/magento cache:flush` and `php bin/magento cache:clean`.

Now hit the **Add to Cart** button it will update the shopping cart forcefully.

Comment: In your code you mention ** [frontName]/[ActionPath]/[ActionName]** . How to identify these because in my module i didn't use these things. All the things are core only.

Comment: @Pinku, are you extending catalog Module?

Comment: I extending my block class from **\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template**  and from this class of constructor i creating object of **\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct**

Comment: @Pinku, your module don't have controller? where did you showing products? otherwise post your sample code with file path? it will help to find bug?

Comment: Yes in my module there is no controller. I am showing products at home page. And the file path is **http://127.0.0.1/magento21/?SID=kae7jepkmjm4sicgf76jb7cpu6**

Comment: i am waiting for your reply

Comment: @Pinku update above `section.xml` to `<action name="checkout/cart/add">` and try again.

Comment: again only msg came, shopping cart didn't update. What shall i do now?

Comment: @Pinku update your thread(full code of custom module) with what you have done. so that we will find where you went wrong? otherwise we can't help.

Comment: I have updated my layout, template and block file code. kindly check once and reply me

Comment: @Pinku, did you extended controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51229/discussion-between-magento-two-and-pinku).

Answer (score 0):

Just add :

```
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
        "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
        "catalogAddToCart": {}
        }
        }
    </script>
```

in bottom of your file .phtml
Or [Download Free Owl Carousel Slider](http://store.ibnab.com/magento-2-extensions/magento-2-free-extension-owl-banner-slider-or-carousel.html) and explore the code it's have the same technique